# clang error when installing pygresql under Mac OS

Tags: python, postgresql, clang, pygresql

I was trying to install PyGreSQL under Mac OS X(10.11.3), but the same clang error occurs when installing from pip and source.

```
$ python3 setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing PyGreSQL.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to PyGreSQL.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to PyGreSQL.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'PyGreSQL.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'PyGreSQL.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_pg' extension
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DPYGRESQL_VERSION=5.0 -DDIRECT_ACCESS -DLARGE_OBJECTS -DDEFAULT_VARS -DESCAPING_FUNCS -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -I/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -c pgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pgmodule.o -O2 -funsigned-char -Wall -Werror
pgmodule.c:3684:3: error: code will never be executed [-Werror,-Wunreachable-code]
                long    num_rows;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

[clang error occurs when installing PyGreSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Aes.png)

I already had PyGreSQL, Xcode and Xcode tools installed in my machine, and I also added the bin directory of PostgreSQL to $PATH.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to compile the module by editing the modules's **setup.py**

Find the line

```
extra_compile_args = ....
```

It's a list of extra compile arguments to pass to clang. One of the extra arguments will be **`-Werror`**, which means "treat all warnings as ERRORS". And as you know an error will abort compilation.

Remove that line, and run `python3 setup.py build` again and you'll see the same line appears, but this time as a warning, and everything goes okay!

Comment: That should solve the problem. It will be fixed in PyGreSQL versions higher than 5.0.3 (see https://github.com/Cito/pygresql/issues/4).

Comment: @Cito It's not: `-Werror` is still there and people [stumble](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53750450/7976758) over it. :-(

Comment: @Phd Thanks for the notification. The actual issue under MacOS has in fact been [solved](https://github.com/Cito/pygresql/issues/4). The -Werror flag has not been removed on purpose - we want errors to show up so we can investigate and fix the root cause. In this case it looks like a different error on CentOS which we will need to investigate. I now subscribed to the pygresql tag in case people report only here instead of using our mailing list or bug tracker.